# Connecting DGN1000SP to DIR-655

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem

I own a DIR-655 router that I have configured with all my port forwarding rules, etc. I had my previous ISP's modem connected to its Internet port and everything worked fine (I turn off the wireless access point on my ISP router and use the one provided by my DIR-655).

I've recently changed ISPs and they provided a DGN1000SP, which I thought would be just as simple. However, when I connect from the DGN Ethernet to my DIR-655 Internet, I do not get Internet access. When I browse connected devices in the DGN admin pages, the DIR-655 is not listed.

I'm not sure how to proceed with setting this up. I've googled, but the only advice I've found involves obtaining the MAC from the DGN admin pages, which I obviously can't do. I've checked with Virgin and they stated that it is supported, but couldn't provide specific advice on my router. Fair enough.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it this morning. It was due to both routers being on the same subnet (my old ISP's router must have been configured to use a different subnet). I changed the subnet on my DIR-655, rebooted everything and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without being there and seeing your setup for myself, if I was in your situation, I would first disconnect the DIR-655 and your new router, then plug in any computer directly to the new one and make sure that the router is set up correctly and that you have internet access.

Next, look at your DIR-655's WAN/Internet Port configuration page and make sure it is either set for DHCP or the correct static settings and not the settings of your old ISP.

If this doesn't help, I would recommend looking at your new router and seeing if you can switch it in to plain modem mode and not router mode, then plug it back in to the DIR-655 and set the DIR-655 to DHCP on the WAN.